# "It also has motivated me..." Is this correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I was hoping somebody with native English could help me find a better way to say this, or if this is fine as it is let me know. Specially the "HAS motivated me", I'm not 100% sure if it's correct or not. Thank you so much in advance!

> Personally, now more than ever I'm super happy to be a tutor, it is exciting to see the students progress and I feel so committed to help them be the best designers they can be. It also has motivated me to read more and be better at my job, it made me fall in love with my career all over again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! Questions that call for proofreading without a specific concern in the text are considered off topic. If you have a specific part of the paragraph that you would like opinions on, then the question can be edited to reflect that. Otherwise, asking for us to read the paragraph and tell you what needs to be fixed is not on-topic here. Have another look at your commas usages, though. Hope this helps!

Comment: How is anyone happy other than personally? Drop the super for any kind of formal writing. You have two run-on sentences, one spliced with the comma after *tutor* and the other with the comma after job. Present perfect *Has motivated* is fine. It expresses completed action up to (or affecting) the present moment. If you've fallen in love with your career again, does that mean that you fell out of love with it at some point?

Comment: @deadrat Maybe she should say "*it made me **feel like I had fallen** in love with my career...*"

Comment: has  motivated me is not a completed action. It is just an undefined time in the past at the moment of speaking.

Comment: @Lambie They don't call it *perfect* because it's without flaw.

Comment: @Hank - No, the original is better than your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

*Has motivated me* is a great choice here, because the tutoring is ongoing (presumably).